# MongoDB Return ToList from bson

Tags: linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

In the following code I am Querying my database to find the specifik _id and that part works fine. Now the problem is that I need to return the result in a wpf datagrid somehow. I usually use List<> and Dictionary<> for this sort of thing but that does not work here.

```
public List<MongoDBModel> MongoDBMeterInfo()
        {
            var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
            var mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            var mongoServer = mongoClient.GetServer();
            var databaseName = "PointToPoint";
            var db = mongoServer.GetDatabase(databaseName);
            var mongodb = db.GetCollection<MongoDBModel>("OCS.MeterEntity");
            var mongodbQuery = Query<MongoDBModel>.EQ(x => x._id, CurrentMeter.MeterUID);
            var found = mongodb.FindOne(mongodbQuery);
        } 

[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class MongoDBModel
    {
        [BsonElement("_id")]
        public string _id { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("EncryptionKey")]
        public string EncryptionKey {get; set;}
        [BsonElement("DataTemplateKey")]
        public string DataTemplateKey { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("LoggerReadsPerDay")]
        public Int64 LoggerReadsPerDay { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("ListType")]
        public int ListType { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("IpAddress")]
        public string IpAddress { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("ReadMode")]
        public Boolean ReadMode { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("DefaultStartTimeStampUtc")]
        public string DefaultStartTimeStampUtc { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("LastSetTime")]
        public DateTime LastSetTime { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("LastReadGSMdata")]
        public DateTime LastReadGSMdata { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("DialBackPort")]
        public int DialBackPort { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("CID")]
        public int CID { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("ActiveFirmwareUpgrade")]
        public string ActiveFirmwareUpgrade { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("QueuedFirmwareUpgrade")]
        public string QueuedFirmwareUpgrade { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("DeviceAcceptedFirmwareActivationMessageOnLastConnect")]
        public Boolean DeviceAcceptedFirmwareActivationMessageOnLastConnect { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("WasConnectionLostLastTime")]
        public Boolean WasConnectionLostLastTime { get; set; }
    }
```

What do I have to do to make it work ? :)

Comment: on a side note, i hope this isn't "production" code - ie, you're not creating a mongo client each time that method is called, are you?

Comment: am i missing something... you're returning a List<> but querying FindOne (on the id)